# vim LineNr and CursorLine colour configuration change

Tags: vim, colors

How do I control the colour of the line number that the cursor is currently on?  I can control the line itself via `:hi CursorLine` and the whole line numbers via `:hi LineNr` but I am getting an ugly Yellow (the default in dark background) for the cursor line number.  This is what I currently have:

```
hi CursorLine     guibg=#222222 gui=none
hi LineNr         ctermfg=DarkMagenta guifg=#2b506e guibg=#000000
```

**Edit 1**: Here is a screenshot:
[image]

**Edit 2**: [link to the colour scheme](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1560).

**Edit 3**: Vim version 7.3.480.

**Edit 4**: All the version information:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Mar 26 2012 08:41:12)
Included patches: 1-480
Compiled by XXX
Normal version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
-conceal +cryptv -cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs
+dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv
+insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape
-mouse_dec +mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm
-mouse_urxvt +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg +path_extra -perl
+persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python -python3 +quickfix +reltime
 -rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline
-sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo
+termresponse +textobjects +title +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit
+visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows
+writebackup +X11 -xfontset +xim +xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/home/XXX/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/inc
lude/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cai
ro -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -
I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/us
r/include/libpng12   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOUR
CE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lg
dk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lc
airo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0
-lrt -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -ltinfo -lnsl
 -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib64/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -
lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a new colour setting:

```
hi CursorLineNr   term=bold ctermfg=Yellow gui=bold guifg=Yellow
```

See `src/syntax.c`.

As [soup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/959304/soup) suggested in the comments, this line can be placed into the `~/.vimrc` which would be easier than editing a colour scheme if it came from `vundle`. Of course, a bug report with patch and a fix would (probably) be appreciate by the maintainers of said colour theme.

Comment: You can place this line in your `.vimrc`, which may be easier than editing your color scheme (if its installed via `vundler` for example).

To see a list of currently set colors, run `:hi`. The `guifg` value from `NonText` is whats used for the other line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

That's it.

You can control the color (fore and background) of the line number columns, and you can control the color of the cursorline, but there is no specific highlighting group for the line number column the cursor line is currently on.

So, you'll just have to do with the nice *mixture* of the two.

Comment: I have added a screen shot showing the "problem" since I do not like that horrid yellow.

Comment: @Sardathrion - Could you post a link to that colorscheme as well?

Comment: I have added it to the main question.

Comment: @Sardathrion - Interesting. I cannot duplicate that behaviour. Could you be using some plugins that affect that?

Comment: No, I just tried by removing ~/.vim and just having the colour theme -- same behaviour. Are you using the same vim version?

Comment: Other themes do it as well: darkblue for example.  Yet pearpuff does it as well but with a darker shade of brown.  Ah, foound something there:  Yellow for dark background, Red for light.

Comment: @Sardathrion - Is there anything in your ":hi" (could be a long list) that resembles that yellow on black? What highlighting group, if there is?

Comment: None whatsoever.  If I comment out the `hi LineNr [...]` line, all the number appear in Yellow (which is the default for dark backgrounds).  If I remove the `set cursorline` from `~/.vimrc`, the problem goes away.  Puzzling.